# Excel Group/Subtotal Keep only the first value of subgroups

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel data set that looks like the following:

```
Fruit      Veg          W1 W2 Q1 W3 W4 Q2
Apple      tomato       0  1  0  1  0  1
Apple      potato       1  2  3  1  4  1
Apple      carrot       3  4  2  0  4  0
Orange     radish       0  1  5  0  2  0 
Orange     kale         4  0  0  5  0  2 
Grape      spinach      0  0  0  1  2  0 
Watermelon lettuce      0  0  0  0  0  0
```

which I would like to group by fruit and subtotal values while keeping the first veg variable for each group:

```
Fruit      Veg          W1 W2 Q1 W3 W4 Q2
Apple      tomato       4  5  5  2  8  2
Orange     radish       4  1  5  5  2  2 
Grape      spinach      0  0  0  1  2  0 
Watermelon lettuce      0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: You can get the unique list using Remove Duplicates, the Veg with Vlookup and the rest with SUMIF().

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a bit more specific about using vlookup for veg?

Comment: Sounds like a job for pivot table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating this table. You can make the list of fruit by using Excel's "Remove Duplicates" function.

```
Fruit       Vegetable  sub_W1   sub_W2  sub_Q1  subl_W3 sub_W4  sub_Q2
Apple       
Orange      
Grape       
Watermelon
```

To get just the first vegetable for each fruit, you can use `VLOOKUP`. Assuming that the "Fruit" cell in your source is A1 and the "Apple" cell in the above table is J2, paste this into K2 (the first blank vegetable cell) and fill it down the column. Vlookup will always return just the first match.

> =VLOOKUP(J2,$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)

To sum the integers, paste this into L2 (the first sub_W1 cell) and right and down to the end of your table.

> =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,$J2,C$2:C$8)

Result:

```
Fruit       Vegetable  sub_W1   sub_W2  sub_Q1  subl_W3 sub_W4  sub_Q2
Apple       tomato        4        7       5        2      8       2
Orange      radish        4        1       5        5      2       2
Grape       spinach       0        0       0        1      2       0
Watermelon  lettuce       0        0       0        0      0       0
```